# RichTextBox blocks DragDrop event

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

I have `DragDrop` and `DragEnter` events on my `SplitContainer.Panel`:

```
    splitContainer.Panel.DragDrop += new System.Windows.Forms.DragEventHandler(this.splitContainerPanelDragDrop);
    splitContainer.Panel.DragEnter += new System.Windows.Forms.DragEventHandler(this.splitContainerPanelDragEnter);
```

It works perfect with every control inside `SplitContainer.Panel` except `RichTextBox` controls.

How it looks like:
[image]

So DragDrop/DragEnter works perfectly in every control inside SplitContainer except controls which is marked yellow color.

What I tried:

1) Set

```
RichTextBox.AllowDrop = false;
```

So I even DragEnter is unavailable with "action is not allowed" cursor.

2) Set

```
 RichTextBox.AllowDrop = true;
```

After this cursor is ok, but it doesnt work because expects additional `DragEventHandler` in other case it doesnt work.

3) Set

```
RichTextBox.EnableAutoDragDrop=false; 
RichTextBox.AllowDrop=true;
```

Same result as 2) variant.

I dont want to set `DragDrop`/`DragEnter` event for **every** `RichTextBox` inside SplitContainer because inside `FlowLayoutPanel` they are created dynamically.

The question is: is there any method like `e.PreventDefault` analog in C#? Or what can I do except setting events for every `RichTextBox` to make it work?

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465988/capture-dragdrop-event-of-richtextbox-c-sharp?rq=1) : `EnableAutoDragDrop=false; AllowDrop=true;`

Comment: I do not quite understand what you want

Comment: I want to make DragDrop/DragEnter events work on EVERY control inside SplitContaner.Panel, but it doesnt work on RichTextBox.

Comment: For me drag drop in a  RichTextBox is working fine
can you better describe what is not working

Comment: Updated post. It works if I set DragDrop to RichTextBox directly. But I set it to splitContainer.Panel. RichTextBox is placed inside it and doesnt allow to DragDrop file on it. So if I try to drug into PictureBox for example - dragDrop works perfectly. If I do same thing on RichTextBox - its doesnt work.

Comment: I think he want to drag and drop right __through__ every control and onto the SplitContainer.Panel, right?

Comment: So he wants to pass event to parent control

Comment: @TaW exactly like you said

Comment: I'm working on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me
I created 2 custom controls

Custom SplitControl

```
public partial class SplitControlCustom : SplitContainer
    {
        public SplitControlCustom()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void ForceDrageDrop(DragEventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            OnDragDrop(eventArgs);
        }

        public void ForceDragEnter(DragEventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            OnDragEnter(eventArgs);
        }
    }
```

Custom RichTextBox

```
public partial class RichTextBoxCustom : RichTextBox
{
    public RichTextBoxCustom()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.AllowDrop = true;
    }

    protected override void OnDragEnter(DragEventArgs drgevent)
    {
        SplitControlCustom parentSplitControl = Parent.Parent as SplitControlCustom;
        if (parentSplitControl != null)
        {
            parentSplitControl.ForceDragEnter(drgevent);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnDragDrop(DragEventArgs drgevent)
    {

        SplitControlCustom parentSplitControl = Parent.Parent as SplitControlCustom;
        if (parentSplitControl != null)
        {
            parentSplitControl.ForceDrageDrop(drgevent);
        }
    }
}
```

Please let me know if it worked

Comment: As it is this assumes a fixed level of nesting.

Comment: Well it should work but I have problem with it. It catches ForceDragDrop, but OnDragDrop doesnt run DragDrop event

Comment: Also fixed level of nesting is easy to avoid if pass parentSplitControl as parameter in RichTextBoxCustom contructor.

Comment: After some changes it works perfectly, thank you, idea was good.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how you can make this work directly. But then, since you are already willing to add a few lines of code while generating the controls, why not add the necessary events via a few lines of **Lambda**..:

Let's assume you have just created a `RichTextBox` and are ready  to add it to some `Controls` collection..:

```
RichTextBox richTextBox = new RichTextBox ();
...
richTextBox.AllowDrop = true;

richTextBox.DragEnter += (ss, ee) => { ee.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy; };
richTextBox.DragOver += (ss, ee) => { ee.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy; };
richTextBox.DragDrop += (ss, ee) 
                       => { splitContainer.Panel_DragDrop(splitContainer.Panel, ee); };
```

The first two lambdas set the effect to copy without any checks; of course you will want to add those and pick the appropriate effect.

The third lambda passes the `DragEventArgs` on the the `DragDrop` event of the containing panel, so now the RTB is actually 'D&D-through' ..

Comment: he doesn't want to set DragDrop/DragEnter event for every RichTextBox  inside SplitContainer

Comment: What I assume he meant is, he doesn't want add events to the form class for the dynamically added controls. He needs to set all sorts of properties anyway, so the three or four lines shouldn't be a problem. - I surely wouldn't want to add a new class for this tiny 'functionality', even if it worked.

Comment: Well @CodeJoy is right, I dont want to implement events for every richTextBox. Its good when you have 1-2 of them. But I can have hundreds richtextbox and that is going to be problem. Especially when some of them are created in runtime, some in disign.

Comment: Did you actually __understand__ my post? Setting those lambdas is not different from setting their location or their names. There is nothing to implement beyond those three lines. __No events at all__! Much cleaner than feeding new class instances with drop targets imo..

Answer (score 0):

Just create a custom `RichTextBox` and override it's `DragDrop` Events.

```
public class CustomRichTextBox : RichTextBox
{
    #region Methods

    #region Overrides

    protected override void OnDragEnter(DragEventArgs e)
    {
        // base.OnDragEnter(e);
    }

    protected override void OnDragOver(DragEventArgs e)
    {
        // base.OnDragOver(e);
    }

    protected override void OnDragLeave(DragEventArgs e)
    {
        // base.OnDragLeave(e);
    }

    protected override void OnDrop(DragEventArgs e)
    {
        // base.OnDrop(e);
    }

    #endregion

    #endregion
}
```

For some reason `RichTextBoxes` seem to handle all `DragDrop` events by default.
In `WPF` the events will propagate till it gets to the control that expects these events. I'm not sure about `WinForms` though.

Answer (score 0):

This is what resolved this issue for me.

I had these two events defined, which should have been good enough

```
MyRichTextBox.DragEnter += MyRichTextBox_DragEnter;
MyRichTextBox.DragDrop += MyRichTextBox_DragDrop;
```

I found that this one is also apparently needed when using a RichTextBox embedded in
certain controls.

```
MyRichTextBox.DragOver += MyRichTextBox_DragOver;


private void MyRichTextBox_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
}
```